# Can you help me identify these pipes and valve sizes?

Tags: water, leak, valve, shutoff

I was met with this (photo included) when asked to help someone.  I am only concerned with the pipe with the red knob.  This is under a mobilehome after the water pit, the shut off to the home.  I am going to try to tighten/repack the nut first but I am curious as to what these pipe size and fittings could be. If I have to replace that valve assembly I was hoping to have an idea before taking it apart if anyone could tell by this pic.  I'm in the USA and I believe this property was built in the 80s. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: If you have to replace it, the best bet is to just take the valve out and take it to the store with you. You can test fittings on both sides to make sure it's the same (highly likely that both ends are the same, but you never know...), then get a new valve to match the threading. Unless you really know what you're doing, this is probably far simpler than guessing ahead of time and/or buying a couple of options to make sure you've got the right one.

Comment: That's most likely what I'll do if needing replaced.  I was just curious as I've never seen this set up.  My house has an inch main coming straight from the pit that reduces to 1/2 inch through the rest of my house around the water heater.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: That's most likely what I'll do if needing replaced.  I was just curious as I've never seen this set up.  My house has an inch main coming straight from the pit that reduces to 1/2 inch through the rest of my house around the water heater.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Mobile Home? With that gray fitting? Very likely Polybutylene.

Probably 3/4", but with nothing in there for scale but my vague sense of typical valve handle size, I would not take that as gospel.

The valve would appear to be pipe threads, so should be strightforward to replace if needed, and easy to get a size on with a ruler or tape measure in hand.

Polybutylene has some major issues as a piping material and is no longer in common use in North America as a result. But it was very popular for a period of time, particularly with mobile home builders. In a non-chlorinated service it *may* be less prone to rapid self disassembly than when on a chlorinated supply.

Comment: I was reading about the gray lines and they were most commonly used in the 80s and for mobile homes.  And I thought this was built in the 80s and it's obviously a mobile home.  I'm thinking pex is the next step for them.  Luckily that's not too hard for me.  Haha.

Answer (score 1):

Take same picture with ruler so we can be more precise.

As it looks right now, it is a 1/2 inch valve with adapter to 3/4 inch hose on the right side. Do not see the left side.

Comment: I am headed back there in a little bit.  Hopefully will just take some tightening or repacking.  Fingers crossed.  The left one is also a mystery to me.  It's not connected and I'm not sure why it is even there.  They have them marked like it's a hot and cold but those are, I'm assuming, both from the meter so both would be cold.

Answer (score 1):

Solved...  I took a longer look at the shut off and determined I only needed to clean up some corrosion and tighten the nut on the stem.  I didn't even have to use more packing.  Also after closer inspection it looks like it is a 1 inch main with a female thread that comes from the meter.  The shut off valve has male threads that connect to the incoming line from the meter side.  The end of the shut off valve, going towards the house, has female threads that had an adapter reduce down to 1/2 inch that then connected to the lines that ran to the rest of the home.